# Что лучше использовать: синглтон или статический утилитарный класс?

Tags: java, классы, static, шаблон-одиночка

Столкнулся с задачей, которую в равной степени можно решить двумя способами. Класс, допустим `DeviceState` обращается к устройству десятки раз в секунду, поэтому каждый раз создавать экземпляр не вариант.

Нужно использовать или синглтон или сделать класс статическим. И так и так работает. Не могу определиться с выбором. По удобству, вроде как, статический выигрывает. Есть ли какая-то разница по памяти и в быстродействии?

```
//singleton
DeviceState ds = ModbusMaster.getDeviceState(); //там происходит return DeviceState.getInstance(connParams);
System.out.println(ds.getLedState());

//full static        
DeviceState.refreshData();
System.out.println(DeviceState.ledState);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Думаю, в вашем случае лучше всё-таки использовать синглтон.
Вот хорошая [статья](http://info.javarush.ru/argnist/2013/07/03/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%B2-Java-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-.html) на эту тему:

> Если Ваш синглтон не поддерживает ни одного состояния, а просто
>   обеспечивает доступ к методам, лучше рассмотреть использование
>   статического класса, так как статические методы гораздо быстрее
>   синглтона, благодаря статичному связыванию во время компиляции.
>
> Если по Вашим требованиям необходимо поддержать состояние, то в таком
>   случае синглтон является лучшим выбором, чем статический класс, потому
>   что поддержание состояния в последнем случае — кошмар, и ведет к
>   неочевидным ошибкам.

А так как у вас сам класс называется `DeviceState`, думаю, он должен поддерживать разные состояния, значит, нужен синглтон.

Что касается производительности:

> Статический класс предоставляет большую производительность, чем
>   синглтон, потому что статические методы связываются во время
>   компиляции.

Но думаю, что особенной разницы в производительности вы не заметите, а стилистически правильнее будет использовать синглтон.

Comment: Если класс final, то jit компилятор вполне умен, чтобы оптимизировать виртуальные методы + в некоторых случаях будет инлайнинг. Т.ч. по производительности они скорее всего будут одинаковые.

Comment: `думаю, что особенной разницы в производительности вы не заметите` - всё-таки тестирование производительности даст более точную оценку. )

Answer (score 6):

По производительности и памяти в вашем случае статика не будет отличаться от синглтона. Имеет смысл использовать именно второй подход (Singletone) т.к. это даст вам возможность в дальнейшем использовать преимущества полиморфизма. В тестовом окружении например можно будет заменить имплементацию `DeviceState` на "заглушку" с необходимой для теста логикой, либо менять реализацию в зависимости от типа устройства с которым общается `DeviceState`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Оба ответа хороши. Вы упомянули о тестируемости. В другом ответе о производительности и целесообразности. Не могу выбрать лучший ответ.

Comment: @Eugene интересно какой вариант вы выбрали для реализации `DeviceState`?

Comment: синглтон, конечно.

Answer (score 4):

Не думайте, как быстрее (до того, как вы провели профилирование), думайте, как правильно.

Статический метод в `DeviceState` означает, что метод относится ко *всем возможным* `DeviceState`. Синглтон означает, что у вас есть ровно один `DeviceState`, и ваши вызываемые методы относятся в точности к нему.

В вашем случае у вас именно второй вариант: у вас одно устройство. Вот и используйте синглтон.

---

Вы не должны задаваться вопросом «как быстрее». Если писать всё «как быстрее», то не нужны ни классы, ни методы, а лишь один большой метод с goto. Улучшать производительность заранее не имеет смысла, «преждевременная оптимизация — источник всех бед».

Ну и несчастная сотня вызовов в секунду — это так мало, что разницу в скорости не заметит никто.